# Bugged character in VSC CLI + OMZsh + Powerline10

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, oh-my-zsh

After installing Iterm2, Oh My Zsh and Powerline10, there is a weird invisible character in the Visual Studio Code console at the start of a line.

What I did:

- Install Iterm2
- Install OMZ
- Install Powerline10 with UNICODE on
- Open VSC

I've tried:

- https://gist.github.com/480/3b41f449686a089f34edb45d00672f28 (setting vscode)
- https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/671#issuecomment-621031981 (installing fonts, the fonts changed, but the unknown character did not disappear)
- https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/671#issuecomment-691504330 (making cli external, but undid this setting as it had no effect)
- looked up other issues with vsc and omz on stackexchange, but none seemed to have this issue
- Reinstalled VSC
- Switch corner style (see below)

This is the generated `.zshrc` file

```bash
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
```

[image]

[image]

After changing banner style, left works, right broken:

[image]

[image]

Comment: needs [mre] with value of your prompt definition

Comment: I've also reinstalled VSC, did not help.

Comment: @user I've added exactly what I did

Comment: @user I've added mre, did you manage to get the same, do you want any system information or more details?

Comment: read my comment again: "_with value of your prompt definition_". show an oh-my-zsh prompt config that **minimally** reproduces the issue.

Comment: @user I've added the `.zshrc` file, hope it helps.

Comment: The entire file is not particularly useful, especially since it tries to `source` other files which you have not included.  Please review the link you got pointed to before, with special focus on what we mean by "minimal".

Comment: Well then it was minimal then, @tripleee, I wrote what I installed and got this problem?

Comment: "Minimal" means it does not contain code that is not required to reproduce the problem. "Reproducible" means with what you provided we should be able to see exactly the same problem. In short, you should not expect us to do basic debugging for you, especially not when you have not provided all the parts which are necessary to actually see the problem.

Comment: No, showing us your `.zshrc` doesn't help. If you read the last lines of the file, you'll see that you should- if anything- be showing us `.p10k.zsh` But preferrably, as I already instructed, show us a [mre]- a minimal prompt configuration that can be used to reproduce this.